# angularjs: scope value doesn't get updated in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ng-if

there are buttons in detail.html file:

```
<div ng-controller="test.views.detail">
<div data-ng-repeat="item in details"  scroll>
    <button ng-click="showDetails(item)">The details</button>
```

in detail.js  file

```
angular.module('test')
.controller('test.views.detail', function($scope) {

    $scope.detailsClicked = false;

    $scope.showDetails = function(item){
        $scope.detailsClicked = true;
    }....
```

in formDetail.html code:

```
<div ng-controller="test.views.detail">
{{detailsClicked}}
<div ng-if="detailsClicked">...
```

Initially it shows `false` for detailsClicked, when I click on button it goes to showDetails function but  value of `$scope.detailsClicked` never get updated! It is straight forward not sure why it doesn't work:(

Comment: Could give us a jsbin or something that we can quickly look at? Or embed it in this post as you can do now? Is the button inside the controllers scope? Also you should never define variables on the scope. They should always be part of an object. That's why the controllerAs syntax is helpful.

Comment: What if you change ng-if for ng-show?

Comment: @botero I tried didn't work

Comment: I think it is because there is an additional scope introduced with ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. do you have any suggestion/solution?

Comment: If you use the ControllerAs syntax instead you should be able to get away with it but to be honest I haven't done Angular in a little while so am a little rusty (but I still remembered this so...). I think the ControllerAs will allow you to specifically refer to the controllers detailsClicked property and so angular will know what to do (I think)  =P.

Comment: How does `formDetail.html` come into play?

Comment: Have you tried moving `$scope.detailsClicked` to `$scope.obj = { detailsClicked: false};`? It's best practice to 'always have a dot in bindings' in earlier versions of angular.

Comment: Check this article for the controlerAs explanation. It has what I think I am trying to get across to you. http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: @Phil there is a main.html in which I have:
<div ng-include="'app/test/views/detail/formDetails.html'"> </div>

Comment: @JimSchubert didn't work:(

Comment: There are two instances of the test.views.detail controller - one in formDetail.html and the other in detail.html. If you want to share state betweeen the two instances, create a service that'll hold the state or use state params if you're using ui-router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using the same controller at two places and expecting the scope object to be the same which it is not. Everytime you call ng-controller in your markup a new scope object will be created.  If you want them to be based off the same data then use a service.

[Here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fo97okvq97Q5difBkzzA?p=preview)

```
app.controller('test.views.detail', function($scope, detailsClicked) {

    $scope.detailsClicked = detailsClicked;

    $scope.showDetails = function(item){
        $scope.detailsClicked.isClicked = true;
    }
});
```

Create a factory/service which will retain the data, make sure the data is a

```
app.factory('detailsClicked', function(){
  var data = {
    isClicked: false
  }

  return data;
});
```